# Laravel 4: A better way to represent this db structure/relationship within laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, relationship

I have the following db table set up

```
  +--------------+    +--------------+    +-----------------------+
  |   users      |    |   clients    |     |   user_clients       |
  +--------------+    +--------------+     +----------------------+
  |   id         |    |   id         |     |      usersid         |
  |   name       |    |   name       |     |        clientid      |
  |   authid     |    |   email      |     +----------------------+
  |   (plus)     |    |   (plus)     |    
  +-------------+     +-------------+
```

I have set up the a relationship table [b]user_clients[/b] with foreign keys to the relevant db, so userid is link to users->id and clientid is linked to clients->id.

Dependant on the Users Authid is how many clients are linked:

Authid 1: User can only have one client associated to them.

Authid 2: User can only have one to many clients associated to them

Authid 3: User has access to ALL clients.

So as i am new to this relationship side of laravel currently i would do a lot of querying to get some details eg:

I would done something like:

```
  $userClient =UsersClients::select('clientid')->where('userid','=',$userid)->get();
```

Then I would probably loop through the result to then get each client details and output to the page.

```
 foreach($userClient as $i ->$cleint){
    echo '<div>' .$cleint->name . '</div>';
    ........
 }
```

Would this be an old way and could it be handled better??

----------------EDIT---------------

i have managed to sort it as the following:

User Model:

```
 public function clients() {
        return $this->hasMany('UsersClients','userid');
  }
```

User Controller

```
  $selectedUserClients = User::find(24)->clients;
```

I get the same out come as my previous result as in client id's 1 & 2, but now how to get the client details from the actual client db basically is there an easier way that the following:

```
  foreach ($selectedUserClients as $key => $client) {
     $clientInfo = Client::select('id','clientname')->where('id','=',$client->clientid)->get();
     echo $clientInfo[0]->clientname;
  }
```

Comment: Can multiple users belong to the same client?

Comment: yeah! sorry, a client can have one to many users as well as users can have one or many clients or all dependant on auth id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The users_clients table needs it's own ID column in order for many-to-many relationships to work.

On your User Model, try

```
public function clients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Client','user_clients','userid','clientid');
}
```

Now you can find the clients assigned to each individual user with
`User::find(24)->clients`.

You could also do the inverse on your Client model...

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User','user_clients','clientid','userid');
}
```

This would allow you to find all the users belonging to each client
`Client::find(42)->users;`

I would also like to mention that it's best practice to use snake case for your id's such as `user_id` or `client_id`.

Your table names should be plural. `users` and `clients`.

Your pivot table should be snake_case, in alphabetical order, and singular.  `client_user`.

This would make working with Eloquent much easier because it's less you have to worry about when setting up the relationships and it might be easier for someone else to help you work on your project.

Instead of `return $this->belongsToMany('Client','user_clients','userid','clientid');` all you'd have to do is `return $this->belongsToMany('Client');` which should keep your app much cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: thansk for this i will look at this and feedback

Comment: thanks again, when you talk about the last statement return $this->belongsToMany('Client'); how will this then determine how to use the pivot table,  i guess using the naming as you mentioned would create its own conclusion that its in the users model and wants clients therefore clients_users relationship dow automatically?

Comment: well thanks for this tried it out and except that the pivot table needed to be named singular client_user, that worked, thanks for saving me some extra work and learning a few more things

Comment: With return $this->belongsToMany('Client');, Laravel should be able to figure out the name of the pivot table as long as the naming conventions are correct.  I was incorrect about it being plural and changed my answer accordingly.  Laravel expects it to be snake case, singular, and in alphabetical order.  So if your pivot table was named client_user, you would not have had to supply a name for it in setting up your relationships.